# How to measure text similarity (Jaro-Winkler) in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

In Oracle we can measure text similarity with Jaro-Winkler like the following:

```
SELECT UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY('STACKEXCHANGE', 'STAMPEXCHANGE') MYSTRING
FROM DUAL;
--98
```

And it turns out that Teradata has Jaro-Winkler too, as explained [here](https://docs.teradata.com/r/CWVY0AJy8wyyf7Sm0EsK%7Ew/luw%7EbGvifzYlXbpj8FcTRQ). Unfortunately I just don't understand the doc and example there.

So far what I can do in Teradata is with EDITDISTANCE:

```
SELECT EDITDISTANCE('STACKEXCHANGE', 'STAMPEXCHANGE') MYSTRING;
--2
```

So, how to measure text similarity with Jaro-Winkler in Teradata? Could anyone please give me some simple example?

Comment: Sounds like `UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY` equals 100 minus `EDITDISTANCE`, no?

Comment: StringSimilarity is supported staritng with TD16.20 FU2 or on the MLE-engine. What's your release?

Comment: @dnoeth. Mine is RELEASE = 16.20.24.01; VERSION = 16.20.24.01 ; LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE = Standard . I dunno how to check its Feature Update

Comment: @dnoeth So how do I use the StringSimilarity with JW to compare 'STACKEXCHANGE' and 'STAMPEXCHANGE' ? Could you please give me simple example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

16.20.24.01 is FU1, FU2 is 16.20.40.01+

This function is not a Scalar function, it's *Table Operator* syntax for set processing. You have to get used to it, but then those operators are very poweerful.

```
SELECT * 
FROM StringSimilarity
 ( ON
     (
       SELECT 1 as id, 'STACKEXCHANGE' as a, 'STAMPEXCHANGE' as b
       -- FROM ...
     )
   PARTITION BY ANY
   USING
     ComparisonColumnPairs ('jaro_winkler(a,b) AS jw_dist')
     Accumulate ('id')
) AS dt
```

Comment: I tried your script but what I got was: SQL Error [3707] [42000]: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.06] [Error 3707] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error, expected something like ';' between the word 'StringSimilarity' and '('.

Comment: My teradata is release 16.20.24.01 so then it's not FU2. Does this mean my Teradata here does not have StringSimilarity option?

Comment: Only 16.20.40.01+ supports StringSimilarity.